# How to increase the text size in all the directions?

Tags: android

I want to increase the size of the text in all the directions if i am normally increasing size by paint.setTextSize() then it just gets increased in onedirection

Comment: what do you mean `direction`?

Answer (score 0):

paint.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);

Unit can be changed as per your requirement.

Comment: Does this set the units of the text as density independent pixels rather than pixels??

Comment: i cant use 18(an integer) as the second arguement